# No sound out of Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, 15.04, microphone, soundcard

There is literally no sound, I've tried every solution online I could find. It start when I unplugged my Microphone. I've tried reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio, booting in different kernel, restarting audio servers, everything. The Sound Card I'm using is the Sound Blaster Audigy 2 ZS, it is being detected, but no sound is coming out the speakers I've hooked up. Everything works in Windows, just not ubuntu.

Edit: The front panel ports work, the headphones and microphone. but the soundcard I'm using has no output whatsoever in linux

Update: I tried unplugging my sound card, and plugging it back in (after several restarts without it), and now there is no sound output whatsoever, not from onboard audio, nor from sound card. Help is appreciated

Comment: I was able to get the sound off the onboard working again by reinstalling pulseaudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to reinstall due to some HDD issues, but everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is just an output selection problem. Go to system settings -> sound and try the different audio outputs. Many graphic cards and onboard sound devices just select hdmi as the standard output...

Comment: I've tried this multiple times and doesn't seem to work. Even when i use alsamixer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Audigy 4 analog output working in Ubuntu 15.04 by selecting the "Digital Output (S/PDIF)" in the `System Settings` > `Sound`.

I believe it was working fine in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (except the zero volume in right channel issue that can be fixed with `alsamixer`) so this issue was probably introduced recently.